# Django allauth get credentials to make further requests on behalf of the user

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm working on a Django project that requires user authentication for BitBucket, I have setup allauth such that users can authenticate with Bitbucket, I just don't understand how to make further requests to the Bitbucket API now that the user is authenticated.

I understand that allauth is purely for authentication purposes, there is just no documentation on how to access and make further use of the authentication, in this case accessing the credentials (oauth_token) such that I can make further requests on behalf of the resource-owner.

Comment: I'm not sure that's in scope of what allauth claims to be able to do - allauth just provides an authentication API for logging in as far as I understand Maybe this will help: http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

Comment: I'm getting this feeling also, I just don't understand why you would authenticate via oauth just for the sake of logging in? Surely the purpose of authenticating is so that you can further access resources on the users behalf? In this instance for example, pulling a private repository from the authenticated users account

Comment: Not necessarily. Some people want to not have to give a password to a random website, but are more OK with login being handled by a trusted source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the authentication details to make a further requests.

### Workflow

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount, SocialApp

bitbucket_app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider='bitbucket')
user_account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)
# User should only have one SocialToken object per SocialApp
# https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py#L137
user_token = useraccount.socialtoken_set.first()

# Credentials to make further requests
client_key = bitbucket_app.client_id
client_secret = bitbucket_app.secret
resource_owner_key = user_token.token
resource_owner_secret = user_token.token_secret
```

### Using credentials with requests and requests_oauthlib

```
import requests
from requests_oathlib import OAuth1
auth = OAuth1(client_key, client_secret, resource_owner_key, resource_owner_secret)
r = requests.get(protected_url, auth=auth)
```

### An example with the bitbucket-api

https://bitbucket-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

```
from bitbucket.bitbucket import Bitbucket
bb = Bitbucket(user_account.uid)  # Initialise with bitbucket username
bb.authorize(client_key, client_secret, 'http://localhost', resource_owner_key, resource_owner_secret)
# Get user repositories as an example
bb.repository.all()
```