# SharePoint API Call for File Upload

Tags: django, azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I'm building an app in Django and trying to upload a file to a SharePoint Online Site but I'm sure I've (at least) got the url wrong for the API call. I have the appropriate permissions allotted to the app in dev.microsoft.com but get back a 500 response when I try to upload.

this is the basic api call I'm trying to use
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

I'm kind of going by these 2 resources to build the url but not sure of the site-id or parent-id. For the {YourSharepointTenant} i got the tenant-id from the Azure Portal under properties. Its a long list of characters that I omitted from my code i posted here

https://www.coderedcorp.com/blog/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-with-django-and-pyth/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content

Here is my code

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     # Get the authenticated user credentials from office365-allauth
    social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='office365')
    access_token = social.extra_data['access_token']

    # build our header for the api call
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token),
    }

    # build the url for the api call
    # Look at https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm for reference
    url = 'https://{YourSharepointTenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/ITSupport/drive/root:/' + design_document + ':/content'
    # Make the api call
    response = requests.put(url, data=open(design_document, 'rb'), headers=headers)
    return response

    super(LaserMaskDesign, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're targeting the graph you should use that url instead https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/siteid/drive....
It is the site API that's your entry point and that will provide you with access to the drive one. Keep in mind that API is in beta so not production ready.
More documentation on this API here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found this resource yesterday that will help figure out the correct url
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#
I'll need to figure out how to add my credentials to the headers since I'm not using that package that the author was using in the article.
I'm guessing I'll need to do something like this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278892/django-allauth-get-credentials-to-make-further-requests-on-behalf-of-the-user